# How to Create/Assign Custom Folder Icon via Command Prompt

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, icons

What I like to do is create folders and assign image/cover arts as the folders thumbnail, rather than generating the standard folder icon. I do this very often *(basically every folder I can bother to find an image for)*.

I setup a script/.bat file so that I can place any image file into the folder, press the hotkey, then it will run a program *(Pixillion)* to convert the image to a .Ico file and hide it.
It will also create a **desktop.ini** file, like what Windows 10 does when you manually set the folder's custom icon.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=%ico%,0
```

after my script is done, Windows 10 recognizes that I have a custom folder icon *(because it doesn't use the generated one, showing the icons inside the folder)*, however it instead shows an empty folder as the icon.
If I place a .url file into the folder, then rename it (manually, does not work from cmd), the folder icon will refresh/update correctly to my custom icon.

---

What I'm looking for, is to get this done without this final manual step.
To set and ***update*** the icon automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Customization via a `desktop.ini` file requires not only the file, but also the folder has to have its `System` or `ReadOnly` attribute set. That's the "Switch" that tells the OS to look for & process the folder' s desktop.ini file. When Windows sets a custom icon, it sets the `ReadOnly` attribute -- this can be verified by adding the `Attributes` column to a `Detail` view in **Explorer**. In **PowerShell**, if you within the folder/directory, y use:

```
### View attriubtes
(Get-Item .).Attributes
# OUtput
PS C:\...\Customized FOlder>( Get-Item . ).Attributes
ReadOnly, Directory

### Set ReadOnly attriubtes
(Get-Item .).Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
# no output when successful

### Clear ReadOnly attriubtes
(Get-Item .).Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'
# no output when successful
```

[image]

Attribue cleared & view refreshed:

[image]

...and back again:
[image]

Comment: My problem isn't getting windows to notice the .ini, it's getting it to "read" it.
You're taking a folder with an already custom icon, then temporarily removing it, then re-enabling it. I want to take a folder without an icon then add one. 
Or in your case, "change" the icon. 

For example, if you change the icon in the .ini, the folder icon will be the same. If you then rename the folder, it will update. If you change the name back, the icon will reset too. Only after it actually "updates" will the new icon be set. 

The only way I know to force the "update", is renaming an .lnk file.